# Restriction of a Lie group automorphism to the subgroup associated to an invariant Lie subalgebra

Tags: lie-groups, lie-algebras, symmetric-spaces

Let $G$ be a Lie group with Lie algebra $\mathfrak{g}$, and let $\sigma \colon G \rightarrow G$ be a Lie group automorphism such that $\sigma^2 = \text{id}_G$. Let $\mathfrak{h}$ be a Lie subalgebra of $\mathfrak{g}$ such that $d_e \sigma (\mathfrak{h}) \subseteq \mathfrak{h}$.

Then, we know from general Lie theory that there exists a unique connected immersed Lie subgroup of $G$, $\iota \colon H \rightarrow G$, with $Lie(H) = \mathfrak{h}$.

**Question**: Does it follow that we get a *restriction* of $\sigma$ to $H$? More specifically, is it true that there exists a Lie group automorphism $\sigma' \colon H \rightarrow H$ such that $\sigma \circ \iota = \iota \circ \sigma'$?

**My attempt**: We have the restriction of $d_e \sigma$ to $\mathfrak{h}$, which is a Lie algebra homomorphism $\mathfrak{h} \rightarrow \mathfrak{h}$. I would like to lift this to a Lie group homomorphism $H \rightarrow H$, but *a priori* this result requires $H$ to be simply connected, which I don't have.

**Context**: I am studying Riemannian symmetric spaces, and this comes up when you try to prove that a totally geodesic submanifold of a Riemannian symmetric space naturally defines a Riemannian symmetric pair. (See Helgason, Remark after Theorem 7.2, page 224).

Comment: Note that $H$ is connected, and then you can use the fact that any element of $H$ is a product of exponentials to lift from the lie algebra

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Hint**: It is easy to see that it suffices to show that $\sigma(H)\subset H$ (and then defined $\sigma'=\sigma|_H$). Now show first that for $X\in\mathfrak h$ you get $\sigma(\exp(X))\in H$ and then use that $H$ is connected.

Comment: That's exactly what I was missing. Thank you!